# Powershell : Get-ChildItem piped to Select-Object returns null Directory property when selecting directory

Tags: powershell, get-childitem, where-object

I am using the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet with the `-Recurse` parameter to enumerate all files *and directories* in a specific path.

If I run : `(Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse | Where-Object -Property Attributes -Value Directory -EQ).Directory`, it returns `$null`.

If I access this same `Directory` property on a file object, this returns the relative path to the search path.
Why isn't the same behaviour observed with a directory object ?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Would you like to post an answer ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, yes, thanks ! Mathias, can you include Santiago's answer in yours ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior differs because it's a different kind of object.

Files are represented by [`FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo) objects (which happen to have a `Directory` property), whereas directories are represented by [`DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo) objects (which do not happen to have such a property, but instead has a `Parent` property for the same purpose).

You can use `Get-Member` to discover these output types and their members:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse |Get-Member
```

If you just want the path to the parent directory, use `Select-Object` with `Split-Path`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse |Select Name,@{Name='ParentPath';Expression={ $_.FullName |Split-Path -Parent }}
```

---

It's worth noting that PowerShell's provider subsystem attaches an ETS property named `PSIsContainer` to indicate whether a provider item is a container type (eg. a directory) or a leaf (eg. a file), so you don't need to inspect the `Attributes` property:

```
Get-ChildItem |Where-Object PSIsContainer -eq $true
```

The file system provider also exposes two parameters to `Get-ChildItem` with which you can filter up front:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory # get only directories
Get-ChildItem -File      # get only files
```